# How to create and deploy a Azure Function App without using annotations

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to execute my existing Java application as an AzureFunctionApp. Is there a way I can do this by creating function.json manually?

1. What is the structure of such an application? I will add jars of my existing application as a dependency
2. How should it be packaged (location of each function.json, host.json, and any other files)?
3. How do I test it locally (what should be appropriate localsettings.json)?
4. Is it possible to do it with regular Maven plugins, without using the Azure Maven plugin?
5. I would like to package it as a docker, what should be the approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Java Http Trigger Azure function.

**Project Structure:**

```java
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───function
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───function
└───target
│   ├───azure-functions
│   │   └───javaazfn-1702025270089
│   │       ├───HttpExample
│   │       ├───lib
│   │       ├───host.json
│   │       ├───javafuncsample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   │       └───local.settings.json
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───function
│   ├───generated-sources
│   │   └───annotations
│   ├───generated-test-sources
│   │   └───test-annotations
│   ├───maven-archiver
│   ├───maven-status
│   │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
│   │       ├───compile
│   │       │   └───default-compile
│   │       └───testCompile
│   │           └───default-testCompile
│   ├───surefire-reports
│   └───test-classes
│       └───com
│           └───function
│   ├───javafuncsample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
├───Dockerfile
├───host.json
├───local.settings.json
├───pom.xml
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Your_storage_connection_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}
```

**function.json:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile" : "../javaazfn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.function.Function.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "req",
    "methods" : [ "GET", "POST" ],
    "authLevel" : "ANONYMOUS"
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "$return"
  } ]
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

- Use the `azure-functions-maven-plugin` to run and deploy your application to Azure Functions.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.function</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaazfn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.29.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>3.0.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>javaazfn-1702025270089</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

- To Dockerize your Java Azure function, create **Dockerfile** in root folder of your project.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
ARG JAVA_VERSION=8
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/java:4-java$JAVA_VERSION-build AS installer-env

COPY . /src/java-function-app
RUN cd /src/java-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    mvn clean package && \
    cd ./target/azure-functions/ && \
    cd $(ls -d */|head -n 1) && \
    cp -a . /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/java:4-java$JAVA_VERSION-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

- Run below commands to run the Azure function:

```
mvn clean install
mvn azure-functions:run
```

- Create and build the Docker image of your Azure function with the commands:

```
docker build --tag <DOCKER_ID>/<Image_name>:<Tag> .
docker login
docker push <DOCKER_ID>/<Image_name>:<Tag>
```

- Deploy the Dockerized function to Azure using the command:

```
az functionapp create --name <APP_NAME> --storage-account <STORAGE_NAME> --resource-group <Resource_group_name> --plan <App_Service_plan> --image <DOCKER_ID>/<Image_Name>:<Tag>
```

**References:**

[Build the container image of Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container?tabs=docker%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-java#build-the-container-image-and-verify-locally).

Comment: thank you ! I had gotten it working , so did not check here. THanks for the detailed notes. It helps !